# Can i visualise image url in some widget?

Tags: android, xml, image, url

Can i visualise image url in some android widget like ImageView or something like this? I do not want to use hard coded images like this  `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"` i want to get the image from some url like this for example `http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg`

Comment: ... use a `WebView`?

Comment: I try this but my case is different. I want to visual exactly in border of some widget like image view or etc. But thanks for you opinion.

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I find the solution.If i use NetworkImageView from Volley bibliothek can set url and everything is ok, and also thank for your minus :)

Comment: Anyway, I tried with the WebView and it worked. Without using any 3rd party library.

Comment: Yes but cam you set clickListener to webview or add him to adapter and etc? this is my case i must set to image click listener

Answer (score 2):

You can use picasso library to get image from url without using asyncTask.

Picasso Link: http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```